# How to import Firefox bookmarks from Linux to Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, firefox, bookmarks, migration

How to import Firefox bookmarks from Linux to Windows? Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
On Linux, when you open up Firefox, click Firefox (orange text) press 'Set up Sync'. Then create an account ... Then enter you account details to the Windows computer.

**Option 2**
Open up Firefox, click Firefox (orange text), click 'Bookmarks', then click Backup under 'Import and Backup' on the top navigation bar. 
 Copy/Save the backup file to usb. Then do the same on the  Windows computer just click Import and select the file.

Comment: I do not have the enty described in Option 2.

Comment: So you see nothing like this? http://itpeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/backup-firefox-bookmarks.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You could either use Firefox Sync or just export the bookmarks to HTML file in Linux and import it in Windows copy of Firefox.

To export the bookmarks to HTML file, open Firefox, then press "Ctrl + Shift + B" to "Show all the bookmarks". In the resulting window click the "Import and Backup" menu and select

- "Export bookmarks to HTML" to export them to a HTML file
- "Import bookmarks from HTML" to import bookmark from HTML file.

Comment: I do not see "Import and backup" entry anywhere.

Comment: Did you press Ctrl+Shift+B to show "Show All Bookmarks" window? Here's how the window is https://i.imgur.com/fEoKnrk.png

Comment: this sequence does not bring any window, it enables the bookmarks pane in the main window.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what your Firefox menu looks like?

Comment: I have found this entry and exported the bookmarks, then I loaded Windows and selected to import the bookmarks from that file. But nothing happens, the bookmarks do not appear.

Comment: Is the bookmark.html you imported empty? If it's too huge then it might take some time.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox uses the same type of bookmark file on Windows and Linux.  You can copy the fix **places.sqlite** from the Linux Firefox profile and copy it into the Windows Firefox profile (places.sqlite stores your bookmarks and browsing history).  You can find the Linux and Windows profiles by following the steps below:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox

Alternatively, you can manually export your bookmarks by going into your Bookmarks Library in Linux (click Bookmarks | Show All Bookmarks | Import and Backup).  Either the default JSON or HTML backups will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty simple to do this. In Firefox, go to your Bookmarks > Unsorted Bookmarks tool (or on some versions, Bookmarks > Organize Bookmarks) and find the option to export your bookmarks.

Save this file onto a common location between your OSes (easiest way is probably a removable flash drive), and in the Windows Firefox, go back into your Bookmarks and select the option to import your bookmarks.

While I haven't tested this myself (I don't have a version of Linux running right now) it appears that all versions of Firefox will export and import the same file formats, so there shouldn't be any problem changing between OSes.

Be sure to let me know if this isn't the case, if I have to I'll get my old crapbook running again and fool around with Linux to see if we can get an answer.